# Tree to array algorithm (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, algorithm, tree

I have a branch model that consists of parent_id and child_id. I want to get an array of parent/children relations without querying each parent for its children.

For this table:

```
Parent_id | Child_id
1         | 2
1         | 6
1         | 9
2         | 3
3         | 10
4         | 7
```

I want to get 1's children, and his childrens' children like this:

```
{2 => {3 => {10}}, 6, 9}
```

without querying each parent for its children.

Is there an algorithm to achieve this efficiently or do I need to go through each parent? Thanks.

Comment: [2 => [3 => [10]], 6, 9] is not valid Ruby. Array or hash?

Comment: @tokland doesn't matter, I'm looking for either hash/array representation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A breath-first search will do the job.

```
def build_tree(i, edges)
    list = {}
    out_nodes = edges.select {|e| e[0] == i}.map {|e| e[1]}.uniq
    out_nodes.each {|n| list[n] = build_tree(n, edges)}
    list
end

edges = [[1,2],[1,6],[1,9],[2,3],[3,10],[4,7]]
puts build_tree(1, edges)
# {2=>{3=>{10=>{}}}, 6=>{}, 9=>{}}
```

Comment: Mistook the times. This runs faster, at 3.6 seconds, 100,000 times. [Benchmark pastie](http://pastie.org/2821220).

Answer (score 2):

A functional and recursive approach:

```
require 'facets'

def create_tree(pairs, root)
  relationships = pairs.map_by { |parent, child| [parent, child] }  
  get_children = proc do |parent|
    (relationships[parent] || []).mash do |child| 
      [child, get_children.call(child)]
    end
  end  
  get_children.call(root)
end

pairs = [[1, 2], [1, 6], [1, 9], [2, 3], [3, 10], [4, 7]]
p create_tree(pairs, 1)
#=> {6=>{}, 2=>{3=>{10=>{}}}, 9=>{}}
```

[edit] Without facets (and now you'll see why I use it!):

```
def create_tree(pairs, root)
  relationships = Hash[pairs.group_by { |p, c| p }.map { |p, ary| [p, ary.map { |p, c| c }] }]
  get_children = proc do |parent|
    Hash[(relationships[parent] || []).map do |child| 
      [child, get_children.call(child)]
    end]
  end  
  get_children.call(root)
end
```

Comment: Facets is not working for me (I get a 500 error). Do you know why?

Comment: Did you try `gem install facets` ?

Comment: I have it in my gemfile (I'm using rails), ran bundle.

Comment: Mistook the times. The first code is 5 seconds, run 100,000 times.

Comment: @zabba, thanks for the benchmarkings. Is then this code faster than the imperative one? It's a bit surprising, maybe ZelluX's code is not the fastest implementation.

Comment: The second code is slightly faster, at 4.5 seconds. ZelluZ's is faster in this case by about 1 to 1.5 seconds (compared to your 1st and 2nd code respectively)